# Prevent image crop when rotating using transform

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, xaml

I'm binding following XAML to `RotateAngle` property and it works great with one "but". Image displays cropped. Image control doesn't seem to be refreshing/resizing after rotation. Is there any way to force resize on image and scrollviewer?

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Image 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                Source="{Binding Input, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToBitmapConverter}}"
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RotateAngle}"></RotateTransform>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html

Go to this page, there is a control called LayoutTransformer. See the sample of that control. It handles rotation, scaling and skewing of images, textbox, listbox, etc.
You will get the code there.
Hope that helps.!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<Image x:name="ctrl"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                Source="{Binding Input, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToBitmapConverter}}"
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding DataContext.RotateAngle, ElementName=ctrl}"></RotateTransform>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
```

Comment: I don't have problem wit binding and actual rotation. Problem is - rectangular image crops when rotated 90 degree. Your XAML works exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use:

```
<Image 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                Source="{Binding Input, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToBitmapConverter}}"
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding DataContext.RotateAngle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"></RotateTransform>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to scale your image down to fit the original image space, you could use my `CalculateConstraintScale` method from here:
[Silverlight Rotate & Scale a bitmap image to fit within rectangle without cropping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801546/silverlight-rotate-scale-a-bitmap-image-to-fit-within-rectangle-without-croppi/6802332#6802332) to scale the image down based on the rotation.

[Click here for a working testbed app created for that answer](http://blog.hitechmagic.com/?p=458) (looks like the image below):

[image: example app image]

Comment: I want Image control to become size of an image when I rotate. Thats why I wrap it into ScrollViewer.

Comment: @katit: Can you add a screen-shot, sketch, or *something* to clarify what you want it to look like. If you want the opposite, the inverse of the CalculateConstraintScale value would give you the new desired sizing factor for resizing the image container. Thanks :)